# How can i center a view in a guideline?

Tags: android-constraintlayout

Suppose i have a horizontal `GuideLine` at 30% of parent and a View (suppose a Button) how can i make that view be centered on the guideline?

Like this:

[image]

**Update:**

The view i'm using here has height based on ratio, and soltuion on answers doesnt works.

Here is current layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgLogo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guideline_30"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineV_75"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/guidelineV_25"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline_30"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_30"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.3" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineV_25"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.25" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineV_75"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.75" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> Using fix width or height

Need to use same `Guideline` for both top and bottom constraint like:

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guideline_30"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guideline_30"
```

xml:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgLogo"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guideline_30"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guideline_30"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:src="@drawable/splash_logo" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_30"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.30" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

output:

[image]

> Using width and height based on the ratio

- As you are using both width and height based on ratio so that it's not centered.
- But to get your desired result you can also set `Guideline = 0.15` (0.3 / 2) and modify `constraintTop` and `constraintBotttom`

xml:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgLogo"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineV_75"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/guidelineV_25"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline_15"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline_15"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.15" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guidelineV_25"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.25" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guidelineV_75"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.75" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

output:

[image]

Comment: I was used Button in example but here i'm using a ImageView, that works when height is set to a fixed value, but when it its set to `match_constraint` and set `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="v,1:1"` the ImageView always stays bellow the guideline, how can i use ratio and still center in guideline?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, updated answer with current layout

Answer (score 6):

You need to constraint both the top and the bottom of the View to the guideline, like so:

```
<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.3" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guideline" />
```

Answer (score 2):

In ConstraintLayout, for centering the View over Vertical axis of any other View Component (e.g. Guidelines, TextViews, ImageViews, layouts, etc.), you can simply follow these two steps, in XML:-

1) `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/componentId"`

2) `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/componentId"`

This will Equally distribute the component's View in the Vertical center.

***BONUS***:-

For centering the View in the Horizontal axis, use

1) `app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/componentId"` 
or
`app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/componentId"`

2) `app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/componentId"`
or
`app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndeOf="@id/componentId"`